# Using the skbuff header file. 

Tags: c++, linux, networking, linux-kernel, header-files

I am developing an application that makes a guess on whether your applications are under attack or not by monitoring the ports of your system. For this I decided to catch live [sk_buff](http://book.chinaunix.net/special/ebook/oreilly/Understanding_Linux_Network_Internals/0596002556/understandlni-CHP-2-SECT-1.html) variables through a kernel module.

But currently I am stuck with the following problem:

Cant access skbuff.h header file. When i do

`#include<linux/skbuff.h>;`

it says it cant find the required header on netbeans. I looked at the code samples online and they have all been able to do

`#include<linux/skbuff.h>;`

without any problems.

P.S. I am running Ubuntu 11.04

[image: screenshot from netbeans]

Comment: Never put absolute paths in `#include` but pass the appropriate `-I` flags to the compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch can you pls explain I flags or give me a link  ..

Comment: Change the inclusion back to `#include<linux/skbuff.h>` and pass `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.30-0/include`when building

Comment: As a side note, you will have almost insurmountable problems using C++ in a Linux kernel module, because the kernel does not provide any of the C++ runtime environment.  Stick to straight C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have almost no idea what *NetBeans* is. I'm guessing that it is some "apparently" *sexy* editor which is able to drive some compilation.

(Actually, I think that for kernel related development, you should learn how to use `make` `gcc` and other tools *manually;* your IDE is hiding some complexity that you need to tackle with: so I think that using any kind of IDE for kernel related code is wrong.).

So you need to figure out how to pass additional `-I` flags to the `gcc` compiler. I can just recall you what the `-I` *dir* flag mean: It is a [preprocessor option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) which "add the directory *dir* to the list of directories to be searched for header files."

As to how to configure your damn *NetBeans* IDE to suit your need, I have no idea! Why don't you just use an editor (`emacs` or `vim`) and run `make` by yourself? Then you'll have to edit some `Makefile`  option, often `CFLAGS`.